# Posting data with image to server in iOS application

Tags: ios, web-services, image-uploading, ios7.1

I am successfully posting UIImage to server, but I need to post a NSString with the UIImage.
Below is the code with which I tried to post UIImage to server.
`selectedItem` is the array where I am storing all selected UIImage from gallery.
The line which I have commented is what I need to send to server.

```
for (int i=0; i<[selectedItem count]; i++) {
  //NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"mid:%@",mid];

  NSData *theData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([selectedItem objectAtIndex:i]);
  NSString *urlString = @"http://retailertoolkit.com/RTK/upload.php";

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
  [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

  NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
  NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
  [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
  NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",mid] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]   dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"iphoneimage.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:theData]];
  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [request setHTTPBody:body];

  NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
  if(connection) {
  } else {
  }
}
```

Comment: what kind of data you want to send with the string?

Comment: i want to send an interger value like 21

Comment: you could add it to the header of the request rather than the body

Comment: How Pete42 can you give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Every parameter of the request has to be added as you are adding the image to the request.
Try replacing `[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",mid] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];` with

```
  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]   dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{parameter_name}\";\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  [body appendData:[mid dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Where `parameter_name` should be your `mid` string's key (parameter name). Good Luck!

Comment: Hi Fahri,I am trying some other idea now,but I want your help here too.Below is the response which I am getting from server one by one.My problem is   that I need to append all the response which I get from server in an array ie as I am getting response it should be added to array.Below is my response.......2014-05-03 16:26:15.727 RTK[484:60b] response data - {"name":"4829712iphoneimage.png"}
2014-05-03 16:26:16.098 RTK[484:60b] response data - {"name":"747375iphoneimage.png"}
2014-05-03 16:26:18.427 RTK[484:60b] response data - {"name":"6656494iphoneimage.png"}

Comment: response data - 6830445iphoneimage.png
response data - 8078614iphoneimage.png
response data - 1409301iphoneimage.png